# two versions of openssl?

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl

I've compiled a fresh apache installation. I compiled it against a fresh install of openssl. I get the following warning in de error.log.

[Tue Feb 14 23:42:36.039364 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 23881:tid 140513492883200] AH01882: Init: this version of mod_ssl was compiled against a newer library (OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017, version currently loaded is OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016) - may result in undefined or erroneous behavior

My openssl in stored in /usr/bin/openssl
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

So where is apache getting its OpenSSL 1.0.2g from?

How can i specify apache that it needs to compile against the OpenSSL 1.0.2k?

Thanks for your support.